# Angular Sequential HTTP Rest request

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have following code in Angular 8:

```js
fetchMedia() {
    this.mediaDetails.forEach(entry => {
        this.fetchSingleMedia(entry); // NEED TO MAKE THIS SEQUENTIAL
    }
  });
}

fetchSingleMedia(entry) {

  this.mediaService.getMedia(entry).subscribe(
    (data) => {
       // MY LOGIC HERE
    },
    error => {}
  );
}
```

The `fetchSingleMedia` method is used by other parts of the code as well. I want to keep the Logic in fetchSingleMedia itself

Now, if I have to sequentially make multiple requests to `fetchSingleMedia` method, how do I need to modify the `fetchSingleMedia` method and way of calling it? maybe using async/await/promise or rxjs?

Edit:

With `concat`, second request is sent before first's response is received. I want second request to go after first request's response is received

Comment: What do you mean by making it sequential? Do you mean synchronous?

Comment: Reactive programming ends with subscribe...don’t subscribe in fetchSingleMedia and use something like forkJoin in fetchMedia. Ugh, please don’t just use promises just because you don’t know RxJS fully yet, this leads to ugly code, mix and matching promises and observables.

Comment: @Shravan I mean one after another in a loop

Comment: @user5155835 what do you want to happen if one fetch fails? Why one after another (if it’s to protect the back end would a delay between requests suffice?)?

Comment: @AndrewAllen even if first fails, second request should be made. Just that, second request should be made after the first request is finished

Comment: @user5155835 you should accept kurt's anwer then as this covers your requirements

Comment: @AndrewAllen The problem with that answer is that the response processing logic in fetchSingleMedia is shifted to fetchMedia. Whereas I want the response to be processed in fetchSingleMedia itself, since they are other parts of the code which invoke it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `concat` to sequentially run an array of observables.

From [the docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat):

> Subscribe to observables in order as previous completes

Build your array of observables first, and then run them sequentially in `concat`.

```js
fetchMedia() {
  const observables = this.mediaDetails.map(entry => {
    return this.fetchSingleMedia(entry);
  });

  concat(...observables).subscribe(singleMedia => {
    console.log(singleMedia);
  },
  error => {
  });
}

fetchSingleMedia(entry): Observable<any> {
  return this.mediaService.getMedia(entry).pipe(
    catchError(() => of('Error')), // TODO: return simple error result here, 
    tap(mediaEntry => console.log(mediaEntry)) // TODO: any processing here
  );
}
```

Note that you will need to handle errors on the individual observables if you want to ignore errors. I have shown a very simplistic way to do this.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhrxha

Comment: There’s also materialise and dematerialise (advanced RxJS) for fine grained control and allowing rest of observables to pass through stream unimpeded by an error.

Comment: Even if first request fails, the second request will still be made, right?

Comment: @user5155835 You can set it up however you want to. Do you want all requests to run even if the first one fails?

Comment: Yes, all requests should run even if any of the request fails

Comment: That's what my example will do. In my stackblitz, I set up a `concat` from a sequence of integers. #2 throws an error, but you still see numbers 3+.

Comment: Also, the response processing logic in fetchSingleMedia is shifted to fetchMedia. Whereas I want the response to be processed in fetchSingleMedia itself, since there are other parts of the code which invoke it. Can the response be processed in fetchSingleMedia itself?

Comment: @user5155835 Again, look at my stackblitz. The subscribe is pushing the values to an array. So it is perfectly possible to handle the emitted values and push them somewhere else.

Comment: @user5155835 You can do any processing you want in `fetchSingleMedia` in the pipe. If you have requirements that you didn't state in your question, please edit your question

Comment: @KurtHamilton Thank you. I've updated the question. In the stackblitz, I need the values.push to happen in getValue and not in concat subscribe

Comment: @user5155835 I've updated my answer and stackblitz. This is going to produce some weird behaviour, but it sounds like it fits your use-case.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Second request is going without waiting for response from first request. I want second request to go after first's response is received/first failed

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: @KurtHamilton just remove concat subscribe from your stackblitz and print something in getValue before return. You'll see that getValue is triggered for all values

Comment: @user5155835 Can you fork and post the link

Comment: @KurtHamilton Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2fjjg Just see the values printed in console

Comment: @user5155835 That proves 1. The function is called when the array is created and 2. The observables aren't run because they're not subscribed. It's not the function itself that's the mocked http request, it's all the stuff that is returned in the observable. Do you expect the function that contains the observable http request to be called sequentially? That would only be important if each http request had to pass some information to the next, but that wasn't in your question. So what's your issue with creating the observables up front?

Comment: I expect the function that contains the observable http request to be called sequentially. Because our server can process only one request at a time

Comment: My whole answer and demonstration was about how `concat` will run each observable in sequence. If you think about that, it means that the observable - *whatever that observable is* - will only be run after the previous one completes. My demo was using `of` + `delay`, but it isn't a giant leap to think about `http.get` instead. I have forked my stackblitz to show this in action with http requests: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frmhrj. Open the network tab and watch the requests. I've put a delay in so you can easily see the order - it's not the cause of the sequential requests.